# State Machine C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am doing a project in Unity with C# and I want to have two drones that will wander in the room, and then attack each other using a state machine.
I have three classes AttackState, ChaseState and WonderState

For example, this is my WanderState Class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Linq;
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class WanderState : BaseState
{
    private Vector3? _destination;
    private float stopDistance = 1.5f;     
    private float turnSpeed = 1f;
    private readonly LayerMask _layerMask = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Walls");
    private float _rayDistance = 5.0f;         
    private Quaternion _desiredRotation;
    private Vector3 _direction;
    private Drone _drone;

    public WanderState(Drone drone) : base(drone.gameObject)
    {
        _drone = drone;
    }

    public override Type Tick()
    {
        var chaseTarget = CheckForAggro();

        if (chaseTarget != null)
        {
            _drone.SetTarget(chaseTarget);
            return typeof(ChaseState);
        }

        if (_destination.HasValue == false || Vector3.Distance(transform.position, _destination.Value) <= stopDistance)
        {
            FindRandomDestination();
        }

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, _desiredRotation, Time.deltaTime * turnSpeed);    //Time.deltaTime * turnSpeed

        if (IsForwardBlocked())     //IsForwardBlocked()
        {
          transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, _desiredRotation, 0.2f);

       }
       else
       {
         float droneSpeed = 2f;
         transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * droneSpeed);     
        }

        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, _direction * _rayDistance, Color.red);

        while (IsPathBlocked())
        {
            FindRandomDestination();
            Debug.Log("Wall");
        }

        return null;
    }

    private bool IsForwardBlocked()
    {
        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
        return Physics.SphereCast(ray, 0.5f, _rayDistance, _layerMask);
    }


    private bool IsPathBlocked()
    {
        Rigidbody obj = new Rigidbody();
        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, _direction);

        return Physics.SphereCast(ray, 0.5f, _rayDistance, _layerMask);
    }


    private void FindRandomDestination()
    {
        Vector3 testPosition = (transform.position + (transform.forward * 4f)) + new Vector3(UnityEngine.Random.Range(-4.5f, 4.5f), 0f,UnityEngine.Random.Range(-4.5f, 4.5f));

        _destination = new Vector3(testPosition.x, 1f, testPosition.z);

        _direction = Vector3.Normalize(_destination.Value - transform.position);
        _direction = new Vector3(_direction.x, 0f, _direction.z);
        _desiredRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(_direction);

        Debug.Log("Got direction");
    }

    Quaternion startingAngle = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-60, Vector3.up);
    Quaternion stepAngle = Quaternion.AngleAxis(5, Vector3.up);

    private Transform CheckForAggro()
    {
        float aggroRadius = 5f;

        RaycastHit hit;
        var angle = transform.rotation * startingAngle;
        var direction = angle * Vector3.forward;
        var pos = transform.position;
        for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++)
        {
            if (Physics.Raycast(pos, direction, out hit, aggroRadius))
            {
                var drone = hit.collider.GetComponent<Drone>();
                if (drone != null && drone.Team1 != gameObject.GetComponent<Drone>().Team1)
                {
                    Debug.DrawRay(pos, direction * hit.distance, Color.red);
                    return drone.transform;
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.DrawRay(pos, direction * hit.distance, Color.yellow);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.DrawRay(pos, direction * aggroRadius, Color.white);
            }
            direction = stepAngle * direction;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Then I have 2 drones, and each of them have a Drone script and a StateMachine script as follows:

```
public class Drone : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] private Team _team;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _laserVisual;

    public Transform Target { get; private set; }

    public Team Team1=> _team;

    public StateMachine StateMachine => GetComponent<StateMachine>();

    private void Awake()
    {
        InitializeStateMachine();
    }

    private void InitializeStateMachine()
    {
        var states = new Dictionary<Type, BaseState>()
        {
            {typeof(WanderState), new WanderState(this) },
            {typeof(ChaseState), new ChaseState(this) },
            {typeof(AttackState), new AttackState(this) }
        };

        GetComponent<StateMachine>().SetStates(states);
    }

    public void SetTarget(Transform target)
    {
        Target = Target;
    }

    public void FireWeapon()
    {
        _laserVisual.transform.position = (Target.position + transform.position) / 2f;

        float distance = Vector3.Distance(a: Target.position, b: transform.position);
        _laserVisual.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, distance);
        _laserVisual.SetActive(true);

        StartCoroutine(TurnOffLaser());
    }

    public IEnumerator TurnOffLaser()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.25f);
        _laserVisual.SetActive(false);

        if (Target != null)
        {
            GameObject.Destroy(Target.gameObject);
        }
    }


    public enum Team
    {
        Red,
        Blue
    }
```

```
public class StateMachine : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Dictionary<Type, BaseState> _availableStates;

    public BaseState CurrentState { get; private set; }

    public event Action<BaseState> OnStateChanged;

    public void SetStates(Dictionary<Type, BaseState> states)
    {
        _availableStates = states;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(CurrentState == null)
        {
            CurrentState = _availableStates.Values.First();
        }

        var nextState = CurrentState?.Tick();

        if (nextState != null && nextState != CurrentState.GetType())
        {
            SwitchToNewState(nextState);
        }
    }

    public void SwitchToNewState(Type nextState)
    {
        CurrentState = _availableStates[nextState];
        OnStateChanged?.Invoke(CurrentState);
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that my drones are going through the room walls

I tried to set for the walls a Mesh Collider or a Box collider, but none of these options worked. Also, for the drones I have a sphere collider.

Does anyone know why this behaviour and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Add a rigidbody to the drone and make sure isKinematic is unchecked.

Comment: I tried what you are saying but if the isKinematic property is unchecked, the drones objects start flying outside of the room. If the property is checked, they act normal but they still go through the walls. Maybe I should add a property to the floor too? I tried with the rigid body but still not working. Do you have another suggestion because I am stuck and I really need to do this project.